# Android xml id naming

Tags: android, xml, naming

There are some questions about naming id in xml layout.

If i have a `Activity` used to create student.
What is the most suitable `id` for the `EditText` of student name?

1. et_student_name
2. et_name
3. et_create_student_name

I always use 3,  because it is relate to the class name.But sometimes i think it is too long. I want to use 2 / 3, it is shorter but i am afraid it will repeated with other xml.

What is the good naming for the `id`?
Is it not good on repeated id in different xml layout?

Waiting for Help, 
Thank you.

Comment: you can give any name you want as long as it meets the requirements of naming conventions. in xml ids, you can use underscore, no Capital letters only small letters. names you can give anything, but you should give something meaningful and unique for it purpose only. it should not be duplicated. select name which you can remember easily for your app or project.

Answer (score 0):

First, unless you are creating a distributed "jar" or "SDK" then you will discover name conflicts at build time. Worry about it then, not now. You are spending more time trying to avoid the problem than it's worth. Sometimes you need to prevent problems, but this isn't one of them.

If you are still worried, then there are 2 prefixes you can consider using. First, add a prefix that is somewhat descriptive of the XML file that has the element. For example, if the XML file is called "create_student.xml" then add "cs_" as the element for the prefix. (FYI - This really sucks when you change the filename, but that rarely happens.)

Second, add a prefix (or another prefix) for the package/class you are targeting. This prevents duplicates for SDK's and other libraries that may end in another developer's build. For example, if your SDK is "Student Registration and Identification" then add "sri_" to each element in the package.

The rest of the name is solely up to you. Having "et_" in the name for an `EditText` is helpful, the rest is going to be either "too long" or "not enough" almost every time.

Comment: Generally not. When you reference them, it will find the right element, but if you change the name of one of them in one XML file, but not in the other, then your app will still compile, but you will have a runtime error. Also, you will have two references to the same "ID" in your R.java file - which some compilers will reject.

Answer (score 0):

to add to @AjayP.Prajapati your ids should not be the same as java keywords like `break`,`continue` ,`switch`,`for` etc..., and also your ids do not need to be **special**. if you have repeated ids the first occurrence will be returned.

Comment: yes thanks, and true. It should not be java special keywords.